# Proper way to wrap native stream in java JNI

Tags: java, linux, file-io, java-native-interface

I am implementing a JNI interface to function that returns pair of the file descriptors(linux tty). I've considered feeding the FD to
`sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().set(fd, native())` and then create input/output streams using `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fd);`, but I am not entirely sure if it will be able to handle 100+ active connections well.

Is there any better way to wrap character device file descriptors in nio/Java 8?

Comment: Create a native method that returns a `FileDescriptor` object and use that object to open a `FileInputStream`.  See http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/jni-filedesc.html for an example.  (That example won't work as written)